# Angular 2 and Angular 4 Dependency Errors

Tags: angular, dependencies, package.json

I started last week in Angular with version 2, after, i installed dependency for projects in Angular 4 and AngularFire 2 v4, but i dont like the documentation of AngularFire2 v4 and i decide return to create a new project in Angular 2, but package.json create all with dependency for Angular 4, How i can change dependency for create a new project in Angular 2 and AngularFire2?

This is my package.json actually when i create new project with angular/cli:

```
{
  "name": "test-angular2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Is posible create Angular 2 project with this? or how i can back to befor versions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your all angular package version to ^2.4.0

```
"@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
```

do same for:

angular router to ^3.4.0

change fire2 to 2.0.0-beta.8

Comment: Do I have to change manually  or is there any option with commands?